# Converting CGA (from Commodore PC40) to RetroTink 5X?

Tags: commodore, cga

I am quite new to the CGA world but I recently got hold on a [Commodore PC40-01](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_IBM_PC_compatible_systems#First_generation_%E2%80%93_Series_I) desktop computer. This has a CGA card but how to connect this to my [RetroTink 5X-Pro](https://www.retrotink.com/product-page/5x-pro), so I can get it to be displayed on my HDMI?

The RetroTink supports these inputs:

> Composite (shared with green RCA jack),
> S-Video,
> Component,
> RGB and
> Composite on SCART connector

Is there by any chance any cables I can buy or do I need to find the soldering iron from the attic? :-)

And what would give the best quality?

Comment: I've never used an RetroTink, but the page says "RGB on SCART". Googling for "CGA to SCART" finds e.g. [this](https://www.electroschematics.com/cga-scart-adapter/), it looks like you need to fiddle with the SYNC. The webpage also says "preferably sync on LUMA or sync on composite", and pin 20 seems to be composite. Possibly you can also buy something like that somewhere.

Answer (score 5):

You need a CGA-to-SCART convertor, such as [this one you can build yourself](https://github.com/profdc9/CGA2Scart) or [this one you can buy](https://www.serdashop.com/CGA2SCART-PRO) (in Europe). You’ll also need a nine-pin cable with appropriate connectors, [such as this one](https://www.serdashop.com/9-Pin-video-cable-2m).

Comment: I should have mentioned that I already have seen that and that it was in my consideration, but it is a little clumsy/bulky in design - to have a SCART mounted in the DB9 seem quite unstable. But maybe I can just add an DB9=>DB9 extension/pass-through cable in front of it so the SCART is lying on the floor?

Comment: Just understood your last part, sorry. I think this is what I will go for, thanks.

Comment: This adapter may not work properly, depending on which device is receiving the SCART composite sync. It's actually not composite sync as you would normally understand, as it's simply a poor man's sync combiner where the VSYNC simpy inverts HSYNC with XOR. That might work with unsensitive CRT TVs as they work with a C64 too, but if this goes into a video processor of some sorts, good luck, but even a simple video ADC would output incorrect syncs to HDMI chip and no HDMI transmitter or receiver chip likes a signal which constantly varies the sync timings relative to each other and video.

Comment: The RetroTink states this, "The TINK-5x accepts sync on luma, sync on composite and c-sync RGB over SCART configurations" and also "Note that TTL-level sync is not supported by the TINK-5x and may damage your hardware." but not sure what this means in this context?

Comment: @Beauvais it means that your sync signals had better be 0.7V or 1V levels (as used by SCART) and not 3.3V or 5V (as used by CGA/EGA/VGA), so hopefully the adapter converts that.

Comment: @hobbs The sync itself would be 0.3V only, the 0.7V would be video only, and the whole composite signal 1V (properly terminated PAL assumed).